# How to make virtual network in Heroku

Tags: heroku

How to make a virtual network in Heroku? I want to deploy backend and frontend into Heroku also I will enable a database. I assume all the apps will scale automatically and be available to each other for the API call and the apps will share the database. How to make a separate network for the separate bunch of apps?

Comment: small tipp here for you: if share the database, you very likely shouldn't split the applications.

Comment: @DenisCornehl so you mean to run everything on the same dyno?

Comment: every app should have its own database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku apps by default are open to the internet, so can call each other.

The only way on Heroku for a private network is the [private spaces](https://www.heroku.com/private-spaces), which is an enterprise feature.

About your assumption on autoscaling: Heroku doesn't (and shouldn't) do autoscaling by default. On paid dynos [you can enable it](https://blog.heroku.com/heroku-autoscaling), there are also third party apps like [hirefire](https://www.hirefire.io/) that help you with that.